# Iterate independently with a for loop/ apply function through a whole segment of R script

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, rscript

I want to iterate with the idea of a `for`-loop or `lapply` function through a whole segment of my R script to see how different my solutions get if I change one value `y`.

If I do it with a `for` loop

```
 numbers <- c(1,2,3,4)
 for (y in numbers){
 ...(lots of code with assignments to global environment, etc.)
 }
```

or with `lapply`

```
 numbers <-(c(1,2,3,4)
 lapply(numbers,function(y){...})
```

both seem to not be independent, i.e. I want that it starts fresh from that point on where I put in this function and not that variables which have been defined in the global environment with the first number 1 interfere with the solution from iterating with number 2 in numbers.

So in essence, I'd like an automated version in R script, instead of manually changing the values for y and see what solutions I get. I guess the variable of interest has to be returned with `return()` or similar so that it does not get lost with the iterations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your question is clear. Can you provide an example of your output?

```
numbers <-(c(1,2,3,4))

# Multiply each number by 2 and see what the output is
lapply(numbers,function(y){y*2})
```

This will take each of your "input" numbers "1,2,3, and 4" and multiply each element by the number 2. The output should be, "2, 4, 6, and 9" respectively.

Comment: Actually with `lapply` and `return()` at the right place it worked! I had to make a function from the code I want to iterate and then `lapply` over it. Question: Is it true though that `for` loop wouldnt work in such situations because it messes with the environment, i.e. because there is no real function after a `for` loop?